# Print to console in visual studio 2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2005

I want to print debug statements to the Output window(or anywhere else I can see it) in visual studio 2005. The advice I've seen has said to use

```
OutputDebugString("message");
```

and to ensure that I have

Options -> Debugging -> Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window checked

while the code builds ok I don't see any output, what's the trick?

Comment: Have you verified that the debug code is actually hit, e.g. by putting a break point on it?

Comment: You need to use Debug command, and not Run.

Comment: Alex: I'm already hitting F5 to Start Debugging.

Comment: Steve: I'm currently unable to set break points as well, I've created a new question here with some more background(it's possibly related to this question as well): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068558/breakpoints-for-c-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 2):

If you're using OutputDebugString, you can also use [SysInternal's DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) to see the output. Until you resolve your Visual Studio debugging issues, DebugView should do the trick.

Comment: Fantastic that works perfectly! I can't the debugger working either so this will at least let me see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You must run in Debug mode first.

Then use the following code (from MSDN):

```
class Test{
static void Main()
{
   Debug.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));
   Debug.AutoFlush = true;
   Debug.Indent();
   Debug.WriteLine("Entering Main");
   Console.WriteLine("Hello World.");
   Debug.WriteLine("Exiting Main"); 
   Debug.Unindent();
}}
```

You will see everything in the Output window. You may have to go to the View->Output menu to make this window visible in the IDE.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm using c++. I'm guessing this is C#?

Answer (score 0):

Alt-2 or View->Output to open the Output Window.  By default it should already be open, it is generally in the tabbed window at the bottom of the IDE (but that will depend on your custom layout), and is labelled "*Output*".

The output is not directed to the *console*, you need to output to `stdout` for that and create a console window for it.

Comment: I have the output window open with the drop down box set to Debug. I see modules being loaded and messages from IExplorer(the process I'm attaching to) but no output from OutputDebugString

Comment: If the process containing the output call is not the process you are attached to, why would you expect to get output at all!?  Or do I misunderstand?  It works for me, although the output is easily lost amongst all the other messages.

Answer (score 0):

If your code does hit that line, then it maybe:

RMB in your VS's output window:

[image]

Check if you have "Program Output" unchecked, if yes, check it!!!

Although this control exist in output windows's context menu, it does impact the output in immediate window as you redirect it.

Comment: May be you can try toggle it? Seems there are some problems with your debugger, and it is in an unstable state...

Comment: Tried that, to no avail. It does seem to be a problem with the way the debugger starts. I can't hit any breakpoints either. It's definitely starting the debugger because the menu item Stop Debugging becomes available.